# How to access the files in the res folder in the imgui conan package?

Tags: c++, compilation, conan, build-system, meson-build

I am using conan to handle dependencies, for those of you familiar with imgui, it provides a series of backends you can include.

When you look at the conan package these are found in the `res` folder.

I need to tell meson to include files in that directory, how do I instruct meson how to find these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to conan so i dont know if there is a better solution,
but i have the following in my conanfile.txt

```
[imports]
res, *glfw.* -> .
```

which puts a bindings folder with the header and the source file in the build directory

then i use them in my CMakeLists.txt with
`"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bindings/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp"`

In a .py script one would do somehting like the following:

```
  def imports(self):
        self.copy("*.cpp", dst="ext/imgui", src=self.deps_cpp_info["imgui"].resdirs[0])
        self.copy("*.hpp", dst="ext/imgui", src=self.deps_cpp_info["imgui"].resdirs[0])
        self.copy("*.h", dst="ext/imgui", src=self.deps_cpp_info["imgui"].resdirs[0])
```

Comment: I discovered how to do it by reading the documentation on the imports method for a conan.py script.